# View controller transition is blocked or delayed

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xcode6, ios8.3

I have this swap view controller method.  It works fine except that something is blocking or delaying the completion block.  I have set the animation duration to zero for testing, but what I'm observing on the device (iPhone6+ iOS8.3 64GB), is that the method transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion: is called but the fromViewController remains onscreen, there is a long delay (about five seconds), then the completion block is called and the fromViewController finally goes away and is deallocated.  The fromViewController is doing nothing at this time.

Has anyone else seen this behavior?  Or know of a good way to determine if the main thread is being blocked and discover who the blocker is?

Thanks Ed.

```js
-(void)swapFromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController toViewController:(UIViewController *)toViewController
{
    if (!toViewController || !fromViewController)
    {
        NSString *exceptionMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s - The 'to' and 'from' view controllers must not be nil.", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__];
        @throw ([NSException exceptionWithName:@"Invalid View Controller Segue" reason:exceptionMessage userInfo:nil]);
    }

    //Sanity check
    toViewController.view.alpha = 1.0f;
    
    [fromViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:toViewController];

    //Configure the toViewController view before the transistion call.
    toViewController.view.frame = self.rootContainerView.bounds;
    
    //Add view to view hierarchy animated
    [self transitionFromViewController:fromViewController
                      toViewController:toViewController
                              duration:0.0f
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                            animations:^{
                                fromViewController.view.alpha = 0.0f;
                            }
                            completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        [self configureConstraintsFromParentView:self.rootContainerView toChildView:toViewController.view withInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];

        //Remove fromViewController from VC hierarchy.
        [fromViewController removeFromParentViewController];

        //Notify the destination view controller it did move to parent.
        [toViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }];
}
```